# Applying colours to a flat shaded mesh

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mesh, vertices

I am attempting to make procedurally generated low-poly terrain and to colour the mesh I've decided to use vertex colouring.

To generate the colours, I use the following code:

```
    Color[] colourMap = new Color[size * size];
    for (int y = 0; y < size; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < size; x++)
        {
            colourMap[y * size + x] = BlendColours(GetNeighbourColours(x, y, heightMap, biomeMap));
        }
    }
```

which works perfectly fine with a normal mesh, as the length of the vertices list is equal to the length of the colour map.

Once I apply flat shading however, the number of vertices is now a substantial amount larger due to each triangle having no shared vertices, so the colour map size no longer equals the new number of vertices and the code no longer works.
The flatshading is applied as follows:

```
public void ApplyFlatShading()
{
    Vector3[] flatShadedVertices = new Vector3[triangles.Length];
    Vector2[] flatShadedUvs = new Vector2[triangles.Length];

    for (int i = 0; i < triangles.Length; i++)
    {
        flatShadedVertices[i] = vertices[triangles[i]];
        flatShadedUvs[i] = uvs[triangles[i]];
        triangles[i] = i;
    }

    vertices = flatShadedVertices;
    uvs = flatShadedUvs;
}
```

What I've tried:

I have tried to get around the error in a hacky way by just setting the length of the colour map to the amount of vertices instead of (size * size) just to see how it works. Obviously, only a small portion of the vertices are coloured as the colour generation code is no longer accurate. This is shown below:
[image]

I'm wondering how to get around this so that I can colour all vertices. I think it should be possible to generate the colours after applying the flat shading, so if it is required to know the length of the vertices list after flat shading, that should be possible.

Thanks!